Dimension reduction to 1 ranked dimension
I have a dataset that contains a comprehensive questionnaire to 13,000 individuals containing about 40 questions regarding disability e.g., can I shower independently? Can I do groceries alone? Etc
The answers are likert-type e.g., big impairment, mild impairment, no problem, not applicable, etc.
I would like to create a (unidimensional) score to measure (latent) disability.
I have implemented some models in Item Response Theory such as a Generalized Partial Credit Model but I'd like to go beyond perhaps using some machine learning if necessary.
Also, I thought of dimensionality reduction, like a PCA with one dimension but I'm afraid the first component would not necessarily have this 'ranking' e.g., higher values mean higher disability..
Some ideas would be appreciated!

If the first PC appears reversed, then negating it will solve that problem. // What do you mean by "implanted some models"?? // If you don't include any variables that directly measure "disability"--whatever that is intended to mean--then it looks like any analysis you perform would be arbitrary.  What basis would you have to support interpreting your score as a disability?

Let me start by stating that I dislike Likert scales (subjective, poorly defined categories, etc.). But that is not your question. I may be missing something here, but why don't you do what every other researcher using Likert scales does? Sum all the scores, to obtain an aggregate score. Here you would need to divide by the number of questions w/o a N/A answer. That final aggregate index will be ~ ordinal (if one assumes that Likert 1+4 really = 2+3), 1 dimensional, with higher values implying higher disability (whatever you mean by disability).

IRT is inherently a dimension reduction technique, but it is predicated on a VALID instrument. That is to say, IRT models will reduce to a single dimension/scale (of ability/disability in this context) IF the items are operating in a manner that justifies such a measurement. Also, it is completely unclear to me what you mean by "going beyond...using some machine learning"...¿is there some alternative algorithm in which you are interested?

Thanks for your valuable comments! The questionnaire is completely validated in multiple publications since early 2000s. I agree that I dislike likert scales too but it's what I have. In my opinion, there are some variables that have higher impact in disability than others e.g., toileting has a higher impact than not being able to dance. Therefore, aggregating (equally weighted) doesn't seem to be a good option. I was thinking of dimension reduction and perhaps using the eigenvalues of the first component as weights for a weighted average of the scales... not sure if that's fine..

If your first component does not have this ranking, then it is a sign that your questionnaire isn't good and needs work.
There are other issues on using PCA on ordinal variables. These have been discussed here in the past but I am having trouble finding them. Maybe someone else can. In any case, it's possible.
Another issue is what to do about "not applicable". The best approach may depend on why  that particular question is not applicable, and that may require analysis on a question by question basis. Otherwise, you may have to just treat NA as missing.
Also, not sure what stage you are at, and what your exact answer scheme is, but I would include a category "completely impaired". And, if you are going to use this questionnaire a lot, then I would validate it in various ways. That could take a while and require a bunch of other people. I was first author on a chapter about constructing self=report measures:
Flom, PL; Supino, PG; Ross, NP (2012). Constructing and Evaluating Self Report Measures. Chapter 8 in Principles of Research Methodology: A Guide for Clinical Investigators ed. by PG Supino and JS Borer. New York: Springer-Verlag

thanks for the input! The questionnaire is validated and extensively used as well as data collected. In this case a not applicable answer could be a question like "do you have pain on your feet?" but this person is amputated, therefore a reasonable answer would be "not applicable". The questionnaire has been validated in the past in this specific context.
